# Kotlin JPQL SELECT CASE ClassCastException

Tags: kotlin, spring-data-jpa, mariadb, eclipselink, jpql

I am using Spring Data JPA with EclipseLink running on MariaDB.

I've declared the following interface method in my repository:

```
@Query("""SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(tj.id) > 0 THEN true ELSE false END 
    FROM TrackingJob tj
     WHERE tj.id = :id AND tj.parent IS NULL""")
fun isMasterTrackingJob(@Param("id") id: Long): Boolean
```

When calling this from code, I always get a ClassCastException:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy258.isMasterTrackingJob(Unknown Source)
at com.xetics.mes.tracking.service.TrackingJobService.assertIsMasterJob(TrackingJobService.java:578)
at com.xetics.mes.tracking.service.TrackingJobService.findAllTraceabilityInformation(TrackingJobService.java:712)
```

My assumption was, that Spring is able to map the return value `0` or `1` to a boolean value. Is that wrong? If I execute the statement directly on MariaDB, I do get `0` or `1` as result.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You're doing nothing wrong.

For MariaDB and MySQL `true` and `false` are aliased to the integers `1` and `0`.

The same results in a simpler form:

```
SELECT COUNT(tj.id) > 0 FROM ...
```